# Find the power series solution of $y''(x)e^{x}+x \,y(x)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

So I've been away from school for a little while and have gotten rusty. I'm trying to touch up on ODEs, specifically power series solutions but keep getting stuck when there are summations of summations, for example:
$y''(x)*e^{x}+x*y(x)=0$

**Attempt:**

Assume $y = \Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n*x^n $

$\rightarrow y' = \Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n*n*x^{n-1} $

$y'' = \Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n*n*(n-1)*x^{n-2} $

$e^x = \Sigma_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!} $

So $y''*e^x+x*y= \Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n*n*(n-1)*x^{n-2}*\Sigma_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!} + \Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n*x^{2n} $

Reindexing k to n (tell me if I can't do that):

$\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty}\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_n*n*(n-1)*x^{2n-2}}{n(n-1)*(n-2)!}  + \Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n*x^{2n} = \Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty}\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_n*x^{2n-2}}{(n-2)!}  + \Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n*x^{2n} = 0$

Here is where I'm stuck since I'm not sure how to combine the summations into one I don't know how to group the two added terms together after further reindexing (likely making $a_0 + a_1*x^2$ or similar added to the series) which would allow me to start solving for the $a_n$ coefficients.

I'm also unsure of how $a_0, a_1$ are generally found, are they just assumed to be $1,0$ for one solution ($y_1$) and $0,1$ for the second ($y_2$) or is it based on the coefficients in the original ODE?

Comment: (you can use \infty to typeset $\infty$, and it looks better to use \sum instead of \Sigma here)

Comment: You must have $a_0\neq0$ if not $a_0=0$ concludes that $y''=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Reindexing and multiplication of $y(x)$ with $x$ is not correct.

> Recall
>   \begin{align*}
> xy(x)&=x\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^{n+1}\\
> &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n-1}x^n\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

In (1) we shift the index $n$ by one to obtain the general term with $x^n$.

> Multiplication of power series is done via *[Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Cauchy_product_of_two_power_series)*.
>   \begin{align*}
> \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k\right)\left(\sum_{l=0}^\infty b_l x^l\right)
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{{k+l=n}\atop{k,l\geq 0}} a_kb_l\right)x^n\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^n a_kb_{n-k}\right)x^n\\
> \end{align*}

*Note:* If no initial conditions are given, the result has to be presented using the coefficients $a_0,a_1, \ldots $ of $y(x)$ in general form.